# Is there a Flutter plugin to Strip/Modify EXIF data from photos, such as GPS coordinates?

Tags: flutter, exif

I've seen a few plugins that allow you to read this data, but nothing to write/remove it.

I know in Android there is a way to do this with the support lib (`https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html#saveAttributes()`)

And there appears to be several examples for Modifying EXIF data on iOS.

But I don't see this in any image or standalone plugins that handle this for flutter.

This all seems a bit strange, since there are several example Flutter Photo Sharing apps using Firebase storage and such. But none, that I've seen, are removing any of this data.

Comment: There is this package but it seems that only allows to see exif https://pub.dev/packages/exif

Comment: There's a porting of exifjs too https://pub.dev/packages/exifdart

Comment: @RobertoManfreda, it looks like both those libraries only read, not write the exif data. https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js looks like a read-only exif tool also.

Comment: @aaronvargas Did you find any solution to modify EXIF data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress/) to strip the Exif (you can optionally maintain it). But I could not find any solution to edit Exif with Flutter.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to implement it from scratch

Answer (score 1):

[native_exif](https://pub.dev/packages/native_exif) seems to be the best option. It supports retrieving and editing each EXIF data.

For example, if you want to remove GPS data and keep other EXIF data, you can try the following code:

```dart
import 'package:native_exif/native_exif.dart';

  // Somewhere in your function
  final exif = await Exif.fromPath(yourPhotoFile.path);
  await exif.writeAttribute("GPSLatitude", "");
  await exif.writeAttribute("GPSLongitude", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for an answer, here is dart code to remove EXIF data from a JPEG by directly modifying the bytes representation. Disclaimer: GPT-4 did help in writing this code.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

Future<Uint8List> stripExif(Uint8List originalBytes) async {
    var image = img.decodeJpg(originalBytes);
    image = img.bakeOrientation(image!);
    final bytesWithExif = img.encodeJpg(image);
    
    const int APP1 = 0xFFE1; // segment of EXIF data
    
    final strippedImage = <int>[];
    
    int i = 0;
    int end;
    while (i < bytesWithExif.length) {
       // segment length is encoded on bytes 2 and 3 of the segment
       int segmentLength = (bytesWithExif[i + 2] << 8) + bytesWithExif[i + 3];
    
       if (bytesWithExif[i] == 0xFF && bytesWithExif[i + 1] == APP1) {
          // Skip APP1 segment
          i += 2 + segmentLength;
        } else {
          // Add segment to new image
          end = min(i + 2 + segmentLength, bytesWithExif.length);
          strippedImage.addAll(bytesWithExif.sublist(i, end));
          i += 2 + segmentLength;
        }
      }
    
  return Uint8List.fromList(strippedImage);
}
```